# Adding constraints to my fitting model using lmfit

Tags: python, constraints, model-fitting, lmfit, function-fitting

I am trying to fit a complex conductivity model (the drude-smith-anderson model) using lmfit.minimize. In that fitting, I want constraints on my parameters c and c1 such that 0<c<1, -1<c1<0 and 0<1+c1-c<1. So, I am using the following code:

```
#reference: Juluri B.K. "Fitting Complex Metal Dielectric Functions with Differential Evolution Method". http://juluribk.com/?p=1597.
#reference: https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html

#import libraries (numdifftools needs to be installed but doesn't need to be imported)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import lmfit as lmf
import math as mt

#define the complex conductivity model
def model(params,w):
    sigma0 = params["sigma0"].value
    tau = params["tau"].value
    c = params["c"].value
    d = params["d"].value
    c1 = params["c1"].value
    druidanderson = (sigma0/(1-1j*2*mt.pi*w*tau))*(1 + c1/(1-1j*2*mt.pi*w*tau)) - sigma0*c/(1-1j*2*mt.pi*w*d*tau)
    return druidanderson

#defining the complex residues (chi squared is sum of squares of residues)
def complex_residuals(params,w,exp_data):
    delta = model(params,w)
    residual = (abs((delta.real - exp_data.real) / exp_data.real) + abs(
        (delta.imag - exp_data.imag) / exp_data.imag))
    return residual

# importing data from CSV file
importpath = input("Path of CSV file: ") #Asking the location of where your data file is kept (give input in form of path\name.csv)
frequency = np.genfromtxt(rf"{importpath}",delimiter=",", usecols=(0)) #path to be changed to the file from which data is taken
conductivity = np.genfromtxt(rf"{importpath}",delimiter=",", usecols=(1)) + 1j*np.genfromtxt(rf"{importpath}",delimiter=",", usecols=(2)) #path to be changed to the file from which data is taken
frequency = frequency[np.logical_not(np.isnan(frequency))]
conductivity = conductivity[np.logical_not(np.isnan(conductivity))]
w_for_fit = frequency
eps_for_fit = conductivity

#defining the bounds and initial guesses for the fitting parameters
params = lmf.Parameters()
params.add("sigma0", value = float(input("Guess for \u03C3\u2080: ")), min =10 , max = 5000) #bounds have to be changed manually
params.add("tau", value = float(input("Guess for \u03C4: ")), min = 0.0001, max =10) #bounds have to be changed manually
params.add("c1", value = float(input("Guess for c1: ")), min = -1 , max = 0) #bounds have to be changed manually
params.add("constraint", value = float(input("Guess for constraint: ")), min = 0, max=1)
params.add("c", expr="1+c1-constraint", min = 0, max = 1) #bounds have to be changed manually
params.add("d", value = float(input("Guess for \u03C4_1/\u03C4: ")),min = 100, max = 100000) #bounds have to be changed manually


# minimizing the chi square
minimizer_results = lmf.minimize(complex_residuals, params, args=(w_for_fit, eps_for_fit), method = 'differential_evolution', strategy='best1bin',
                             popsize=50, tol=0.01, mutation=(0, 1), recombination=0.9, seed=None, callback=None, disp=True, polish=True, init='latinhypercube')
lmf.printfuncs.report_fit(minimizer_results, show_correl=False)
```

As a result for the fit, I get the following output:

```
sigma0:      3489.38961 (init = 1000)
    tau:         1.2456e-04 (init = 0.01)
    c1:         -0.99816132 (init = -1)
    constraint:  0.98138820 (init = 1)
    c:           0.00000000 == '1+c1-constraint'
    d:           7333.82306 (init = 1000)
```

These values don't make any sense as 1+c1-c = -0.97954952 which is not 0 and is thus invalid. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not runnable.  The use of `input()` is sort of stunning - please do not do that.  Write code that is pleasant to read and separates i/o from logic.

To make a floating point residual from a complex array, use `complex_array.view(float)`

Guessing any parameter value to be at or very close to its limit (here, `c`) is a very bad idea, likely to make the fit harder.

More to your question, you defined `c` as "evaluate `1+c1-constant` and then apply the bounds `min=0, max=1`".   That is literally, precisely, and exactly what your

```
params.add("c", expr="1+c1-constraint", min = 0, max = 1)
```

means: calculate `c` as `1+c1-constraint`, and then apply the bounds [0, 1]. The code is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Unless you know what you are doing (I suspect maybe not ;)), I would strongly advise doing a fit with the default `leastsq` method before trying to use `differential_evolution`. It turns out that `differential_evolution` is not a very good global fitting method (`shgo` is generally better, though no "global" solver should be considered as very reliable).  But, unless you know that you need such a method, you probably do not.

I would also strongly advise you to plot your data and some models evaluated with what you think are reasonable parameters.